# How do I share a private YouTube video with someone?

Tags: youtube, privacy, sharing, youtube-studio

I have uploaded a YouTube video and marked it as private.

Now I want to share it with someone. I have tried to share it a few times, but they have not received any email notification.

What is the proper way of sharing the video?

Comment: I'm not sure if YouTube likes to change it all the time or what ... It took me a while to find it today, so I recorded a simple video how you can do it (as of Feb. 2020): https://youtu.be/JK8m-KfFLgI

Comment: You can try this workaround:
Go to: https://www.youtube.com/subscribers
Once inside the page that loads the previous version of YouTube Studio, click on Video manager.
Click Edit next to the video you want to share privately.

Answer (score 8):

The original accepted answer is out of date. The current steps are:

1. Navigate to https://www.youtube.com/
2. Click your account icon at the top right, and select "Creator Studio" from the menu.
3. In the videos panel click the "Edit" button next to the video you with to share.
4. **On the "Basic Info" tab, ensure, the privacy is set to "Private". Otherwise, the option to share with specific people will be hidden.**
5. On the "Basic Info" tab, click the "Edit" button just under the privacy drop down list.
6. The primary action button to submit the form will say "Share". Click that button to save your changes.

Comment: Will this work with non gmail email ids?

Comment: only if they have a Google account @keshav

Comment: This answer is also out of date: https://i.imgur.com/yvq8Xwq.png (you can set the "visibility" to private, but there are no further options to share)

Comment: @dylanh724 I think you're using the Beta version of YouTube Studio. In that case you find the sharing option in this way: Studio dashboard > videos > select your video > go on the left > other functions> share privately

Comment: Thank you gibbone! That was super unintuitive and all the other answers made me think I was crazy. Clearly things have changed significantly.

Answer (score 3):

### 11.01.2019 - present day

- click on your profile icon on top right
- select **Creator Studio**
- go to **Video Manager**
- select video you want to share
- click on **<kbd>Edit</kbd>** button
- add your +1 person under Private selection

[image: 4]

Comment: If questions are true duplicates of one another, please close them as such rather than answering in both places.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this information from the YouTube site?

I would imagine that the email has been blocked as spam.

#### Getting Started: Sharing videos

There are many options for sharing a video you've found on YouTube. Here are a few:

1. Have YouTube send your friends an email with a link to the video - just sign into your YouTube account, click on the "Share" link underneath any video, and then scroll down to the "Send this video from YouTube" box. Enter any email address you want and an optional personal message, then click "Send"
2. Send a video URL to your friends directly - just click on the "URL" text box to the right of any video, copy the text, and paste it to anyone in an email message or IM window
3. Share to a social network - just click on your favorite social network underneath a video (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, orkut, etc), sign into that social network (if necessary), and follow the instructions to send the video to your profile or directly to your friends.

#### Having trouble sharing a videos?

If your friends haven't received the YouTube videos you've shared with them, please ask them to check their spam folder to see if the emails were filtered there. Adding service@youtube.com to their address book or filter exception list may help avoid this problem in the future. You may also want to confirm that you're entering the right email addresses when you share videos.