# How do I share private YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, sharing

It's been asked already in many places but all the answers literally everywhere are out of date, eg. [How do I share a private YouTube video with someone?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7588/how-do-i-share-a-private-youtube-video-with-someone)

Here's how it looks like today, I have a video and I want to share it with one and only person on YouTube, the others should not be able to access it even if they guess the link (so "Unlisted" is not an option).

I must admit that YouTube's UI is a nightmare for me, I've been using Google's products for many years now and even stuff like Google Analytics is more obvious than this, for example, my video is not listed on My Channel (I know it's private but shouldn't I see it?) so I have to access it through YouTube Studio and even there "Dashboard" is empty, but when I click on "Videos" I can finally see it but I can't allow anyone to watch it (check the screenshot), have they stopped allowing it? What's the purpose of private videos then if I can't share it at all?

[image]

Comment: You can try this workaround:
Go to: https://www.youtube.com/subscribers
Once inside the page that loads the previous version of YouTube Studio, click on Video manager.
Click Edit next to the video you want to share privately.
From the old YouTube Studio (Creator Studio) it should work and load the private video sharing tool.